# Tuition obligation during corona crisis

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, yeshiva-school, legal-documents

Is one obligated to continue to pay tuition to a Jewish day school when it closes due to an unforeseen/unforeseeable situation, such as the current coronavirus pandemic? (Assume a standard school contract that doesn't mention such a scenario, and that payments are in installments throughout the year.)

Comment: A similar question could be asked about the pay of the teachers.

Comment: You can also ask about people renting halls - do they get a refund for their booking which they can no longer take advantage of? I’ll have to ask my Rebbe - he was just paskening on these types of questions last I spoke with him before we were sent home.

Comment: In Jewish law there is no such thing as holiday pay or payment for nothing. Unless a contract has been made one never has to pay for no work. That the person will starve is no more your concern than anyone else.

Comment: @interested But there _is_ a contract here. The issue at hand is whether an oness to this degree can absolve someone of the contract I think.

Comment: https://baltimorejewishlife.com/news/news-detail.php?SECTION_ID=1&ARTICLE_ID=129285

Comment: The Bais Havaad has answered many of these questions but in the form of general guidelines. [baishavaad.org/daily](https://baishavaad.org/daily) . (Regarding the official guidelines that they reference in a couple of the videos, those were given initially for the Lakewood area.(Disclaimer)

Answer (score 5):

See https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Halachot_Related_to_Coronavirus#Laid_off_Workers_Because_of_Corona

> [Rabbi Zylberman](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/949287/rabbi-michoel-zylberman/coronavirus-and-laid-off-employees/) on yutorah.
>
> Mordechai b"m 343 writes that if there's a decree in the town that the teachers can't teach the teachers should still be paid. Rama C.M. 321:1 cites this Mordechai and applies it to any worker in 334:1. Netivot 334:1 limits the idea of the Mordechai to a teacher and not other employers since a teacher is paid for sachar betela. Shach 334 holds that this opinion of the Mordechai only applies if majority of the town ran away because of a crisis but if only a minority runs away then the employee isn't entitled to payment.
>
> The Sama 334:2 argues with the Mordechai and holds that since the employee can't work and both aren't at fault and both couldn't foresee this the employer is exempt.
>
> Aruch Hashulchan 334:10 has another approach. If the situation prevents the worker from working then he is entitled to pay but if he runs away then he isn't.
>
> Rabbi Zylberman explained from Mishpat Poalim we think that this is a case of Hamotzei Mchavero Alav Harayah, whoever is holding onto the money can claim that he is exempt from paying or returning the money. Rav Asher Weiss in Minchat Asher 2:106 says that they should make a compromise, and Rav Bleich (Contemporary Halachic Problems v. 4) thinks that we follow the Rama. Once the Chatom Sofer had a case in his town and he felt that they should pay but he couldn't force everyone to pay it so he told them to pay half. Rav Yona Reiss had a case where they made a compromise.

Comment: I  don't think any of this applies here, since neither the school nor the teachers are employees of the parents.

Comment: I understand the s'ma. But I am not in the inyan. They seem to talk about having to run away. I am sure in our case there is some method he can teach at least some of the children and no need to be paid for nothing.

Comment: While interesting and a good starting place, this doesn't apply to teachers/schools/students who are expected to continue remotely.